# Change layout of the sharepoint 2010 list using visual studio 2012

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2010

I have created a custom list in Sharepoint 2010 using VS2012. Now I have to modify the user interface. In Schema.xml file, I see following code:

```
<Forms>
  <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
</Forms>
```

I want to create separate custom forms and change the look and feel.

Note: I don't want to use sharepoint designer.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to get started is to create a new form using sharepoint designer.

Open the new form in advenced view and copy all the markup.

Create a new module in your solution/feature.

In the content for that module create a new page called NewForm.aspx and paste all the content from sharepoint designer.

Adjust the module manifest to make sure you are uploading the page to the right spot. You should be sending it to: /List/Forms

Add another entry in your schema xml for that page.

You can then modify that new page as you like and deploy it using your solution